# How do I update package in an org that already contains the earlier package?

Tags: managed-package, beta-managed-package, package

I want to upload the updated package version 2 in package org but the package org already contains version 1 of the package. Now it might be a conflict if I upload the version 2 package in package org. If we delete components from package org, what will be effect on trial org or past package versions? Please suggest an efficient way to do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are installing the release package then I think you won't face any problem updating it. But if you are uploading beta then you just need to uninstall the old package and install the version 2 on the org.

Comment: i am uploading the beta version in package org but in package org ,there is existing managed package version 1. now what i have to follow during uploading managed beta version 2. and ya i am not having much knowledge about the package realize.

Comment: Have you tried installing the beta version 2? You are getting any error? In manage packages versions get updated and you don't need to uninstall the already uploaded package.

Comment: no i didnt try yet for that.